# app_offline.htm doesn't return response to ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, wcf

I have created a file app_offline.html, contents:

```
{
   "ServerUnavailable":"true",
   "IssueType":"Maintenance",
   "ErrorMessage":"Servers are currently down for maintanance, please try again later"
}
```

And posted to my server.

From my app i want to show a message about server downtime.

When i navigate to my server via Google Chrome i see:

[image]

Okay, all is cool.

But when i do a ajax request from my app:

```
$.ajax({
  // bla bola bla
})
.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  // bla bola bla
})
.fail(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  // HERE I WANT TO DISPLAY A MESSAGE
});
```

The XMLHttpRequest all properties are not defined.
I have tried all:

response
responseBody
responseType
responseXML
responseJSON
status
statusText

**Where i can find the response that i see in browser? Or what am i missing?**

Comment: Please, can you provide the request args? Specially make sure that the URL that you're trying to retrieve is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

This code actualy never enters the fail function since the request didn't fail.

When you request the app_offline.html file it will just give back

```
{
   "ServerUnavailable":"true",
   "IssueType":"Maintenance",
   "ErrorMessage":"Servers are currently down for maintanance, please try again later"
}
```

Which doesn't generate any errors and will be stored in the "response" variable of your .done function.

Comment: nop, you are incorrect. the code goes into fail with 503 error code

Answer (score 0):

I think you are ignoring the Http Header requirements. The header should be `Content-Type: application/json` but you are using a html file so IIS serves this file with `text/html` header.

Take a look at this https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".syx" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".tab" mimeType="text/plain" />
      </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Before you apply this you might want to change your file's extension. It might be easier this way.